# Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, bios

I have a Lenovo i310 running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4).
The wifi works only if I follow this odd procedure:

- switch on laptop
- press for a few seconds the power button
- switch on laptop again

The hardware switch are all on. Wifi is enabled in the BIOS.

Differences I noticed so far.

Command: `lspci -nnv |grep ualcom`

When wi-fi is NOT working:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:abcd] (rev 01)
```

When wi-fi is working:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
```

Command: `rfkill list`.

When wi-fi is NOT working:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: yes  
Hard blocked: no
```

When wi-fi is working:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: yes  
Hard blocked: no  
2: hci0: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: yes  
Hard blocked: no  
3: phy0: Wireless LAN  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT 1:

Command: `lsmod | grep ath`

When NOT working: **NO OUTPUT**

When working:

```
ath10k_pci             45056  0  
ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci  
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core  
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core  
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

EDIT 2:

Command: `dmesg | grep ath`

Output when NOT working: **NO OUTPUT**

Output when working:

```
[    9.243817] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0  
[    9.486944] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2  
[   11.457948] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp  
[   11.457951] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0  
[   11.459947] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c  
[   11.459950] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map  
[   11.459951] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00  
[   11.459952] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c  
[   11.465771] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0  
[   14.008726] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

EDIT 3:

Command: `dmesg | grep 02:00`

Output when NOT working:

```
[    0.209512] pci 0000:02:00.0: [168c:abcd] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.209554] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xa1000000-0xa11fffff 64bit]
[    0.209668] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1
[    0.209669] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot D3cold
[    0.209720] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.865508] pci 0000:02:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt
```

Output when working:

```
[    0.206106] pci 0000:02:00.0: [168c:0042] type 00 class 0x028000  
[    0.206181] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xa1000000-0xa11fffff 64bit]  
[    0.206388] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold  
[    0.206471] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI  
[    0.862590] pci 0000:02:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt  
[    7.131821] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0  
[    7.416193] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2  
[    9.380874] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp  
[    9.380878] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0  
[    9.391091] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: I've pinged the Wifi guru, Chili555, and he'll be happy to assist :)

Comment: What is the output of `lsmod | grep ath`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `lsmod` suggests that the driver module isn't loading automagically as expected. Let's give it a little push. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo ath10k_pci  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and test.

Comment: I added the line to the modules file.
Then shut down.
Wi-fi not working, however as soon as I brute force the shutdown (pushing the power button) the wi-fi works again.
I do not think forcing the module load is the problem.

Comment: Please reboot and when it is not working, please show us: `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: added to edit 2

Comment: Very weird! May I also see, when not working: `dmesg | grep 02:00` I wonder if there is an ACPI or IRQ issue.

Comment: It is really weird! Anyway added EDIT 3

Comment: See here: `[168c:abcd] type 00 class 0x020000` The system sees it as an ethernet device, 168c:abcd. After you brute force it, it is correctly recognized as 168c:0042. I'm studying it. I wonder if the card is seated correctly in the slot. Also, I suggest you reset the BIOS to defaults. I will be Googling...

Comment: ok. maybe at this point it is more a question for Lenovo? what do yo think? I am also seriously wondering whether there is just a physical contact problem, since actually a couple of times it worked without brute forcing it. However I use windows at work (during the day) and ubuntu (in the evenings), so I doubt the physical contact hypothesis. I will try to reset the BIOS to default. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would ask Lenovo for sure. You may have better luck on their forum: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/English-Community/ct-p/Community-EN